# REST not working on bluemix due to CORS

Tags: json, rest, post, cors, ibm-cloud

I am new to bluemix, I have simple Rest service with few functions and called from angular js. 
Here is below in Rest service class:

```
@POST
@Path("getTest")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getTest(@QueryParam("accountId") String accountId) throws Exception, IOException {
    System.out.println("HelloResource.getTest() "+accountId);
...
...
  return Response.ok(dbData).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
          .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, HEAD, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS")
            .build();
}
```

Further, in client angular js is invoking this rest service in

```
 $scope.searchcall = function(acctid) 
      {
         $http({
          method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://javarestapi61.mybluemix.net/api/hello/getTest',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
          data:  {"accountId": $scope.accountId}
        }).success(function (data) 
          {
//never been successful onblue mix
          }).error(function(data) {
              alert("failure1"); //always landing here..
          });
      };
```

Looks like this is best solution which i tried. I am not sure, what i can try further to allow explicit permission on bluemix Rest application. BTW above app when deployed on local liberty, it works well.

Also i can access the same Rest service on bluemix, if i change return type as String and access via browser..(without even any additional permission)

Further, I saw that Chrome network details shows that, Preflight  request go and returns with 200 (OPTIONS) then second request is actual POST which never succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is modify the method to :

```
 public Response getTest(@QueryParam("accountId") String accountId, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception, IOException{
  //then your code
 }
```

Now after that add the following:

since the browser looks for `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in the Allow Origin Header, you need to make sure this is getting added in the following line:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:8080");
```

To get the `http://127.0.0.1:8080` you can use :

```
request.getRemoteAddr() + ":" + request.getRemotePort();
```

But if the browser looks for localhost then go for the :

```
request.getRemoteHost().
```

Avoid adding `*` because some browsers will not still allow that.
Hope that solves your problem.

And of course add this to the header:

```
 response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, HEAD, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS")
```

Comment: But the preflight is an OPTIONS request, so the resource method never gets a chance to send the required preflight headers. That's why we use a filter instead.

Comment: @peeskillet For me the filter, for some reason, did not work. So tried the above method and it worked.

Comment: But yes, had to add `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, HEAD, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS")`

Comment: No luck guys..

currently, I open angular html page deployed on bluemix with abcd.mybluemix.net. With an action, opens hits to REST service. So i guess origin would be abcd.mybluemix.net, right? and not browser IP of UI app or host.
I have added abcd.mybluemix.net but it still it does not work..
return Response.ok(dbData).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://abcd.mybluemix.net/")...
but no help...

Comment: Here is Chrome....requests with headers..
General
 Request URL:http://<abcd>.mybluemix.net/
 Request Method:GET
 Status Code:304 Not Modified
 Remote Address:169.54....

Response Headers
 view source
 Connection:Keep-Alive
 Content-Type:application/octet-stream
 X-Backside-Transport:OK OK

Request Headers
 view source
 Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
 Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
 Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
...
 Cookie:CoreID6=147..... 
 Host:<abcd>.mybluemix.net
 ...

Comment: BTW i did not get HttpServletRequest object as param
so i have added below line
public Response getTest(@QueryParam("accountId") String accountId,@Context Request request,@Context Response response) 

but did not help ..it never entered inside method anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Finally when everything else that i tried did not work, below solution worked for me..
I have just added another separate url in my rest service class..

@Path("/getTest")

@OPTIONS

public Response getOptions() {
    return Response.ok().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS").header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With").build();
}

Basically response of options have the "allowed" methods given by service..